# how to describe a linear transformation on (x, f(x)).. and what's not a theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm studying the behaviors of a family of functions $f(x) = \frac{x - x \bmod b}{b} + k \bmod b$ parametrized by integers b, k, as a dynamic system. I only have around 2 weeks left and I was always stuck having to describe anything about the periodic points, coz as u can see, iterates of $f$ isnt really easy to formulate. Then, today I just realized that the graph of $f(x)$ looks just the same as a Bernoulli map $B(x) = (kx) \bmod 1$, which is much more studied and hopefully can give me a direction so I could finally finish my paper aaa. Anyway, yes, $f(x)$ looks like a Bernoulli map with parameter k, but the graph is linearly transformed with the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
bk  &  0\\
 k  &  bk-1
\end{bmatrix}
(edited, i got it wrong)

But it's the graph that is transformed, and I think this is more like a 2d thing? and I'm trying to study f(x), a 1D map. So I'm not much sure how precisely it should be stated and here I am asking for help. For now, what I know is that the line $y = x$, with which the cobweb diagrams are used, will be transformed as well. I have already calculated it'll turn to $y = \frac{(b - 1)}{b}x$ if I transform $f(x)$ to Bernoulli, so the corresponding Bernoulli map variation will be $x_{n+1} = \frac{(b - 1)}{b}((kx_{n}) \bmod 1)$.

**EDIT: For some reason, $B(x)=(kx) \bmod 1$ with just $y=x$ for cobweb is making the expected dynamics of $f(x)$ instead of $B(x)=(kx) \bmod 1$ with $y=\frac{(b - 1)}{b}x$ a.k.a $B(x)=\frac{(b - 1)}{b}((kx_{n}) \bmod 1)$ with $y=x$.** This is good but I also wonder why.

Also, this is for a research paper, I'm just a senior high student and I didn't really have experience writing math papers so I would also like at least your opinion on what exactly should be a proposition, a theorem, and maybe a property (in a paper). What I found out so far is it's mostly subjective, a theorem is much more important proposition, a property (statement) I just found in a paper related to whatever I'm working rn.

So, I've been through papers stating divisibility rules for some primes, they used propositions for them.. what's in my paper is a generalized version for arbitrary prime divisors and integer bases, the one I defined $f(x)$ as. Is that important enough to be considered a theorem, or is a theorem something that is generally agreed upon the math community or smth? also when describing stuff like "$f(x) = bk - 1 - f(bk - 1 - x)$ for the dynamic system of $f(x)$ on ℤ" do I say properties instead of propositions?

Would very very much appreciate any insights about these. Two weeks left and im dead aa

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In MathJax, use `a \bmod m` to get $a \bmod m$. Also, note that the description on the tag "research" specifically says "Do not use this tag just because your question is related to research you are doing."

Comment: @jjagmath I thought whether it is right to write something as a proposition over a theorem (or vice versa) in a paper belonged in the tag. Thanks for the heads up!